# Change html content at a specific video timecode of a html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I have an html5 video player and at the bottom of this video i want to display questions at a specific time range.
For example from 0sec to 2sec it's question 1, from 2sec to 4sec it's 
question 2...

I've managed to change the content of my DOM element at a specific timecode. I'm pretty close to what i want. But there is some bug with my method :

```
var interval = setInterval(myFunction, 10);

function myFunction() {
  if (Math.floor(vid.currentTime) == 2) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<i>de 2 à 4 secondes</i><br><br><input type="checkbox" name="answer3" value="answer3"> answer 3<br><input type="checkbox" name="answer4" value="answer4"> answer 4<br>';
  }
}
```

If you click right after the change the checkbox is reset.
Any other method to do that ? Or another library i should use ?

Here is my example :
https://jsfiddle.net/5stLf6f9/28/

Comment: The code is working as expected, could you explain little more about the issue?

Comment: two things, you probably want to use the `addEventListener("timeupdate")` to track the time (ties it better to the video element) and also have a flag to indicate which group was last activated so if your code is called again within the same time period then the checkboxes don't reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the code was because you were immediately overwriting the HTML content of the `#demo` div when the interval fired. Hence any selection was immediately overwritten with the newly created `input` element.

To fix this you can store the last time the HTML was updated and only change the content when the new time code boundary is hit. You can also simplify the logic by placing the HTML in an array and doing some simple maths on the timecode to work out which index of the array to show. You can also use the `timeupdate` event instead of polling the video properties every 10ms. Try this:

```js
var video = document.getElementById('myVideo'),
  demo = document.getElementById('demo')

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', setQuestions);
video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  demo.textContent = 'Done!';
});

var questionData = [
  '<i>de 0 à 2 secondes</i><br><br><input type="checkbox" name="answer1" value="answer1"> answer 1<br><input type="checkbox" name="answer2" value="answer2"> answer 2<br>',
  '<i>de 2 à 4 secondes</i><br><br><input type="checkbox" name="answer3" value="answer3"> answer 3<br><input type="checkbox" name="answer4" value="answer4"> answer 4<br>',
  '<i>de 4 à 6 seconde</i>s<br><br><input type="checkbox" name="answer5" value="answer5"> answer 4<br><input type="checkbox" name="answer6" value="answer6"> answer 5<br>',
  '<i>plus de 6 secondes</i><br><br><input type="checkbox" name="answer7" value="answer7">  answer 6<br><input type="checkbox" name="answer8" value="answer8"> answer 7<br>'
]

function setQuestions() {
  var index = Math.floor(video.currentTime / 2);
  if (video.dataset.lastIndex != index) {
    demo.innerHTML = questionData[index] || questionData[questionData.length - 1];
    video.dataset.lastIndex = index;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"> Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<p>
  <span id="demo"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.